# Excel Macro Automating Cells and Columns editing

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to automate insertion of columns and moving of data within a certain part of a spreadsheet.
Currently What the Macro is

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Rows("6:9").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("F5").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("G5").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H5").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I5").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D6:D9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10000"
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "20000"
    Range("C8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "30000"
    Range("C9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "40000"
    Range("C10").Select
End Sub
```

How do i change it so that it will update dynamically when i select a new set of rows again ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but please take a moment to read on [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). It will help you alot.

Answer (score 2):

With the following edited macro you can select any number of rows to be inserted and with inputbox

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
Dim newRows As Range, newRowsAddress As String, previousRow As Range
Dim ColumnLetter As String, i As Long, j As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set newRows = Application.InputBox("Select rows to insert", "New Rows", , , , , , 8)
If newRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
Set previousRow = newRows.Offset(-1).Resize(1, Columns.Count)
newRowsAddress = newRows.Address

'    Rows("6:9").Select
'    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'    Range("F5").Select
'    Selection.Cut
'    Range("E6").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Range("G5").Select
'    Selection.Cut
'    Range("E7").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Range("H5").Select
'    Selection.Cut
'    Range("E8").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Range("I5").Select
'    Selection.Cut
'    Range("E9").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
newRows.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Set newRows = Range(newRowsAddress)
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, 5 + newRows.Rows.Count).Address, "$")(1)
newRows.Columns("E:E").Value = Application.Transpose(previousRow.Columns("F:" & ColumnLetter).Value)

'    Range("A5").Select
'    Selection.Copy
'    Range("D6:D9").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste

newRows.Columns("D:D").Value = Application.Transpose(previousRow.Columns("A:A").Value)

'    Range("C6").Select
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10000"
'    Range("C7").Select
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "20000"
'    Range("C8").Select
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "30000"
'    Range("C9").Select
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "40000"
'    Range("C10").Select
j = 1
For i = newRows.Rows(1).Row To newRows.Rows(newRows.Rows.Count).Row
Range("C" & i) = j * 10000
j = j + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Two New Rows
[image: Two New Rows]
or Seven New Rows
[image: Seven New Rows]

Comment: You can remove the commented text from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "Use Relative References" option when recording your macro.